# Changing The Delimiter to CTRL+A in Python CSV Module

Tags: csv, unicode, hadoop, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a csv file with the delimiter ctrl+a.  I'm going to have to eventually write the file to hadoop and I'm unable to use a standard delimiter.

Currently I'm trying this:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = "\u0001")
for item in aList:
     writer.writerow(item)

f.close()
```

However, the outputted excel file doesn't appear to be written correctly...
Some rows are condensed into one block, while others will have one field in the first and then the rest condensed into the second block, etc.

Is the error where I'm setting up the writer object, or am I just not familiar with separating files this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the nonprinting "group separator" character, which can be represented in python code as '\035'

see http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif for some other nonprinting characters if you need more.

It may be helpful to include more context about why you want to use nonstandard delimiter. And whether Excel parsing of the file is necessary, or just a quick check to see if the file might be parsed properly by the target system, Hadoop.